# How to scroll to specific element inLatest version of Appium using Java?

Tags: java, android, scroll, appium, android-uiautomator

My element is not visible on screen but when i use .isDisplayed() method i get true my code is as below

```
Point xy = send_mail.getCoordinates().onScreen();
        int a=xy.getX();
        int b =xy.getY();
        System.out.println("a" + xy.getX() + "b" + xy.getY());
        TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
        touchAction.moveTo(a, b);
```

send_mail is xpath of element to be found. This is tracelog help! I cannot use while loop to iterate until element is not displayed as it it considered visible y appium.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement$1.onScreen(RemoteWebElement.java:402)
    at testcases.TestcaseFunctionsAndroid.offlinesearchservice(TestcaseFunctionsAndroid.java:764)
    at testcases.TestCasesAndroid.TC9(TestCasesAndroid.java:279)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: I just want to scroll to particular element and that element doesnot have id or accessiblity id. It has xpath throught which i am trying to find it. Any positive help is appreciated. I have also tried through uiautomator script which is mostly used by other solutions provided but can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Following is the method to get coordinates of perticular element:

```
public int[] getCoordinates(String xpath, AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) throws Exception {
         //Locate element for which you wants to retrieve x y coordinates.
        //int arr[] ;
         int arr[] = new int[10];
         //Get the middle co-ordinates of the element and store in  the array.
         WebElement element = driver.findElementByXPath(xpath);
         int leftX = element.getLocation().getX();
         int rightX = leftX + element.getSize().getWidth();
         int middleX = (rightX + leftX) / 2;
         int upperY = element.getLocation().getY();
         int lowerY = upperY + element.getSize().getHeight();
         int middleY = (upperY + lowerY) / 2;
         System.out.println("x co-ordinat: "+middleX+"\n y co-ordinat: "+middleY+"\n left x axis: "+leftX+"\n right x: "+rightX);
         arr[0]= middleX;
         arr[1]= middleY;
         arr[2]= rightX;
         arr[3]= leftX;
         return arr;
         }
```

Then Use:

```
            int[] co_ordinates = takeaway.getCoordinates(Xpath of from Element  , driver);
            System.out.println(" x cordinate: " + co_ordinates[0] + "\n y cordinat: " + co_ordinates[1]);
            int[] dinates = takeaway.getCoordinates(Xpath of To Element, driver);
            TouchAction touch = new TouchAction(driver);
            touch.longPress(co_ordinates[0], co_ordinates[1]).moveTo(dinates[0], dinates[1]).release().perform();
```

Comment: Hi i tried this first but it doesnot work. You know it finds that element in the list so it won't scroll and will click the last element visible on screen instead of scrolling to this element.

Comment: Means you want to swipe particular element?

Comment: yes excatly, I need to and that too dynamic. Problem is my app dont have ids need to do with xpath only...

Comment: I have updated answer ...please try this & let me know what is happening?

Comment: thanks I will try and let you know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the code but it's not working. Problem is that my list doesn't scroll. What shall I do? I think I have scrolling issue. what shall I do now as I don't think touch action is performing scrolling. Help with that.

Comment: for scrolling Use :((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");

Comment: Or in above answer instead of longPress use press .

Comment: I have problem as I get list of elements how can i scroll as dimensions of elements after last visible element is same . 417 X438 Y
417 X777 Y
417 X1116 Y
417 X1455 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y
417 X1773 Y this is eg of my phone which shows 6 elements after that it needs to scroll for other elements but after 6 elements all have same DIMensions how can i scroll to particular eelement.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you want next?

Comment: I can scroll now. But problem is Now I have 20 elements in list that i can find by author count. But how can i scroll untill element that i am finding should be visible on screen?